# Nebensatz mit einer Frage?

Tags: difference, question, subordinate-clause

Wie kann man eine Frage in einem Nebensatz erkennen, wenn die Frage nicht am Anfang steht?

Wenn es um das schriftliche Deutsch geht, dann ist es leicht zu unterscheiden (zwischen 1 und 2)

(HS,NS) Kann ich meinen Nachtisch essen, wenn ich meine Suppe gegessen habe?

(NS,HS)
1) Wenn ich meine Suppe gegessen habe, kann ich meinen Nachtisch essen.
2) Wenn ich meine Suppe gegessen habe, kann ich meinen Nachtisch essen?

Wie macht man das im mündlichen Deutsch?

Comment: Durch Hinzufügen des Wörtchen "dann", an der richtigen Stelle. "Dann kann ich..." Aussage, "kann ich dann..." Frage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Das geschieht durch die *Intonation*, also die Sprachmelodie - Das Fragezeichen ist eigentlich nur ein schriftlicher Ersatz dafür.

Im Deutschen (wie im Englischen) wird eine Frage mündlich durch eine sogenannte "steigende Intonation", also das Ansteigenlassen der Tonhöhe zum Satzenede hin ausgedrückt. Der gleiche Satz als Antwort hat dagegen eine absinkende Tonhöhe zum Satzende.